# How to extract polynomial coefficients in Java?

Tags: java, string, text-parsing, polynomial-math

Taking the string `-2x^2+3x^1+6` as an example, how how to extract `-2`, `3` and `6` from this equation stored in the string?

Comment: I have tried extracting using + as a delimiter to extract -2x2 3x and 6 ..then what to do

Comment: How about running "-2x^2" through the extraction with delimiter 'x' ? (btw. do you have plans how to handle e.g. 3x^3-2x^2-3 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not giving the exact answer but some hints:

- Use [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace) meyhod:

  replace all `-` with `+-`.
- Use [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace) method:

  ```
  // after replace effect
  String str = "+-2x^2+3x^1+6"
  String[] arr = str.split("+");
  // arr will contain: {-2x^2, 3x^1, 6}
  ```
- Now, each index value can be splitted individually:

  ```
  String str2 = arr[0];
  // str2 = -2x^2;
  // split with x and get vale at index 0
  ```

Answer (score 2):

```
    String polynomial= "-2x^2+3x^1+6";
    String[] parts = polynomial.split("x\\^\\d+\\+?");
    for (String part : parts) {
        System.out.println(part);
    }
```

This should work. Sample output

```
polynomial= "-2x^2+3x^1+6"
Output:
-2
3
6 
polynomial = "-30x^6+20x^3+3"
Output:
-30
20
3
```

Comment: Thank you Manoj  but this would not work in the condition if - sign comes example "-2x^2-3x^1+6"

Comment: @Manish did a small change. It should work for this case now. I have made the + sign match optional. This way negative nos will also be matched.

Comment: I was wondering what if the sequence is entered as 6+3x^1-2x^2 ..in this case the matching pattern will change..

Comment: @Manish ya..then pattern will change..if that is case i think that a better approach is to first split on basis of +/- sign, and then further extract the digit from the splitted portion