# Getting polynomial exponents in java

Tags: java, exponent

I am trying to get the exponents of a polynomial in java.

I found something similar here 
[How to extract polynomial coefficients in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415573/how-to-extract-polynomial-coefficients-in-java) but I can't seem to be able to modify that for my needs, the argument of the .split() method.

I tried this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 


Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String s1 = new String();
System.out.println("Enter a polynome:");
s1 = scanner.nextLine();
    scanner.close();

String[] Exponents = s1.split("\\-?\\+?\\dx\\^");
for (String exponent : Exponents) {
    System.out.println("Exponents:");
    System.out.println(exponent);
    }
```

for input: -2x^2+3x^1+6 
the output is:

Exponents:

Exponents:
2

Exponents:
1+6

Thanks for the help,

Comment: Can you show the polynomial whose coefficients you are trying to extract? Examples usually help. So does showing any attempts you have made.

Comment: `.split` is a blunt tool that may not be good enough for this use.  Try regular expressions.

Comment: Or hand-write logic the scans the string searching for ^ and extracts the number immediately following. Or, overkill for your current problem, implement a recursive-descent expression parser, which would be able to handle things like x^(y+2)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to split on + and - to get the individual terms.  Then for each term, use split again to return whatever comes after the ^, or 0 if there's no ^.

```
String[] terms = expression.split("(-|\\+)");
for (String term : terms) {
    String[] parts = term.split("\\^");
    System.out.println("Exponent: " + (parts.length > 1 ? parts[1] : "0"));
}
```

Comment: I never thought of it as a two level split. Thanks for the help!

Comment: In the case the first monome has no sign use "(-|\\+)" else use "(\\+-?)".

Comment: @Floris why do I need a tweak?  Using `split` in the way I have doesn't require the first coefficient to have a sign.